# timerEvent within enterFrame function?

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I'm calling a timerEvent function from enterFrame, it's running the timerEvent function on everyFrame. Is there a way to control it?

I've got my bullets firing function with timerEvent of 500, so it shoots a bullet every half a second on 24fps. It's working fine for now. Now I want to change bullet speed and skin with respect to weapon.

```
////////////////////////////////
//this function is called first time within an EnterFrame function
///////////////////////////////



function weaponCheck():void
{
switch (weaponState)
{
    case STATE_GUN :
        gun();
        break;
    case STATE_DOUBLE_GUN :
        doubleGun();
        break;
    }
}


function gun():void
{
trace("single gun");
laserTimer = new Timer(600);
laserTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
laserTimer.start();
function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var tempLaser:MovieClip = new Laser();
    var tempGunBlast:MovieClip = new Gun_blast_01();
    tempLaser.x = player.x +((player.width/2)+12);
    tempLaser.y = player.y;

    tempGunBlast.x = stage.mouseX + 104;
    tempGunBlast.y = tempLaser.y;
    Lasers.push(tempLaser);
    addChildAt(tempLaser,1);
    addChildAt(tempGunBlast, 3);

    if (tempGunBlast.currentFrame >= tempGunBlast.totalFrames)
    {
        removeChild(tempGunBlast);
    }

    }

}

function doubleGun():void
{
trace("Double gun");
doubleGunTimer = new Timer(400);
doubleGunTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener2);
doubleGunTimer.start();
function timerListener2(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var tempLaser:MovieClip = new doubleG();
    var tempGunBlast:MovieClip = new Gun_blast_01();
    tempLaser.x = player.x +((player.width/2)+12);
    tempLaser.y = player.y;

    tempGunBlast.x = stage.mouseX + 104;
    tempGunBlast.y = tempLaser.y;
    Lasers.push(tempLaser);
    addChildAt(tempLaser,1);
    addChildAt(tempGunBlast, 3);

    if (tempGunBlast.currentFrame >= tempGunBlast.totalFrames)
    {
        removeChild(tempGunBlast);
    }
}
}



///////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Following function is called within an enterFrame event function
/////////////////////////////////////////////////

function playGame():void
{
weaponCheck();
blah1();
blah2();
blah3();
testForEnd();
}




function testForEnd():void
{

if (level == 3)
{
    laserTimer.stop();
    weaponState = STATE_DOUBLE_GUN;
    weaponCheck();
}


}
```

So when the game runs for first time, it works fine and uses the timer event of 600 to hit the bullets, but when level == 3 and weaponState changes, the 2nd firing function doubleGun(); is called but it starts to fire the bullets on a per frame count, not on a controlled timerEvent. Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: you need to use deltas for that , and track time differences yourself, if you stick timer events in an enterframe event loop you are going to get in trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you drop timers and use enter frame listener as a manner to count time? You are already calling `weaponCheck()` from an enterframe listener. Make it so that the actual `gun()` and `doublegun()` calls will only generate animation, such as firin' mah lazers and blasts, and the main function will just count time.

```
function weaponCheck():void
{
    this.reloading+=this.weaponFiringSpeed; // you alter this to make your weapon fire slower or faster
    if (this.reloading<FULLY_RELOADED) return; // we are not yet ready to fire
    this.reloading=0;
    switch (weaponState) // and here we fire with the gun state
    {
        case STATE_GUN :
            gun();
            break;
        case STATE_DOUBLE_GUN :
            doubleGun();
            break;
    }
}

function gun():void
{
    trace("single gun");
    var tempLaser:MovieClip = new Laser();
    var tempGunBlast:MovieClip = new Gun_blast_01();
    tempLaser.x = player.x +((player.width/2)+12);
    tempLaser.y = player.y;
    tempGunBlast.x = stage.mouseX + 104;
    tempGunBlast.y = tempLaser.y;
    Lasers.push(tempLaser);
    addChildAt(tempLaser,1);
    addChildAt(tempGunBlast, 3);
}
```

And similarly double gun. `FULLY_RELOADED` is a constant, `reloading` is a variable used to track time, it should be a property of the one who's firing.

Note, this approach requires you to manage your "tempGunBlast"s elsewhere, perhaps in the very `weaponCheck` function, if so, modify it as follows:

```
function weaponCheck():void
{
    if (tempGunBlast) if (tempGunBlast.currentFrame >= tempGunBlast.totalFrames)
        removeChild(tempGunBlast);
    this.reloading+=this.weaponFiringSpeed; // you alter this to make your weapon fire slower or faster
    if (this.reloading<FULLY_RELOADED) return; // we are not yet ready to fire
    ... // rest of code unchanged
```

You will most likely not be able to copypastely implement this, but please try.

Comment: thank you very much vesper, sounds very logical, i'll try to implement  it tonight and will share the results.

Comment: hey, thanks vesper its done :D, you are the man. Last night i put in almost 4 working hours on it but could think of it this way, I found it very helpful, now my other stuff as putting new weapons and enemies will be much easier. I might be chewing your brain in future regarding as3 development on this project. Million thanks.